# filter list with nested dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, filter

I have a list consisting of dataframes. The list is created by a funtion that I cannot control. Therefore, each dataframe holds more information then I need. The structure of every dataframe in the list is the same. What I need to do is to filter out rows by values of one column and write this to a new list. The list contains over 1000 dataframes of the same structure.

```
historical_file[1]
$daily_kl_historical_tageswerte_KL_00001_19370101_19860630_hist
   STATIONS_ID MESS_DATUM QN_3 FX FM QN_4  RSK RSKF SDK SHK_TAG  NM VPM PM  TMK UPM  TXK  TNK TGK eor
1            1 1937-01-01   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA       0 6.3  NA NA -0.5  NA  2.5 -1.6  NA eor
2            1 1937-01-02   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA       0 3.0  NA NA  0.3  NA  5.0 -4.0  NA eor
3            1 1937-01-03   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA       0 4.3  NA NA  3.2  NA  5.0 -0.2  NA eor
4            1 1937-01-04   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA       0 8.0  NA NA  0.2  NA  3.8 -0.2  NA eor
5            1 1937-01-05   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA       0 8.0  NA NA  1.4  NA  4.5 -0.7  NA eor
6            1 1937-01-06   NA NA NA    5  5.2    7  NA       0 6.0  NA NA  0.2  NA  2.0 -2.4  NA eor
[ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 17296 rows ]

$daily_kl_historical_tageswerte_KL_00003_18910101_20110331_hist
   STATIONS_ID MESS_DATUM QN_3 FX FM QN_4  RSK RSKF SDK SHK_TAG  NM VPM PM   TMK UPM  TXK   TNK TGK eor
1            3 1891-01-01   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA      NA 0.0 4.3 NA  -3.6  88  0.5  -5.9  NA eor
2            3 1891-01-02   NA NA NA    5  0.0    0  NA      NA 2.7 4.1 NA  -2.8  84  0.0  -5.8  NA eor
3            3 1891-01-03   NA NA NA    5  2.5    1  NA      NA 3.7 3.9 NA  -0.2  69  2.1  -6.2  NA eor
4            3 1891-01-04   NA NA NA    5  8.2    1  NA      NA 8.0 6.4 NA   1.8  90  3.7   0.6  NA eor
5            3 1891-01-05   NA NA NA    5  1.9    1  NA      NA 7.7 4.7 NA  -2.5  87  1.5  -4.2  NA eor
6            3 1891-01-06   NA NA NA    5  2.5    1  NA      NA 8.0 3.5 NA  -5.8  88 -4.0  -6.9  NA eor
```

I would like to filter every dataframe by `MESS_DATUM`. So on an individual dataframe I would do

```
historical_file_new<-historical_file%>%filter(MESS_DATUM>'2000-07-01')
```

How to do that on this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass your `filter` into `lapply`

```r
library(dplyr)

l <- list(iris,iris)

lapply(l,function(x) filter(x,Species=="setosa"))
#> [[1]]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#> 11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
#> 18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
#> 20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
#> 21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
#> 22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
#> 24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
#> 25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
#> 26          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 27          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
#> 28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 31          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#> 34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 35          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 36          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 38          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1  setosa
#> 39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 41          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
#> 45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
#> 46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 48          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#> 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#> 11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
#> 18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
#> 20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
#> 21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
#> 22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
#> 24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
#> 25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
#> 26          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 27          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
#> 28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 31          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
#> 33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#> 34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 35          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 36          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 38          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1  setosa
#> 39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 41          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
#> 45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
#> 46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
#> 47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 48          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>